# How to set up a chrome breakpoint when a certain string is first encountered while parsing a page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, scope, google-chrome-devtools

I want to set up a breakpoint in chrome

consider the following string: 'testval123'

if this string is manufactured by concatenation say test+val and then again couple of steps +123 is added. The first instance this is parsed as a whole I want the breakpoint to pause. it could be a variable name dynamically created or value assigned to a variable. The first occurrence of this string in whatsoever form I want chrome to pause there.

How do I set it up?

Comment: How is this question relevant to any of the tags here?

Comment: @Dekel this is within client side javascript. pertains to chrome browser, is a debugging process, we need to arrest and inspect the scope and this is done in chrome dev tools panel. I am not sure which tag is out of context?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code showing how you're dynamically creating variables? Are you using `eval()`?